# Converting PathForResource To String Returning nil Swift

Tags: macos, swift, webkit

When loading a local resource file in a mac app

```
let urlpath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myResource", ofType: "html");
```

Converting the resource path to a `string` for `NSURL` always returns `nil`

```
    println("resource path = \(urlpath)") <---resource logged ok

    web.frameLoadDelegate = self;
    let requesturl = NSURL(string: urlpath!)

   println("URL String  = \(requesturl)"),<---- returns nil

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requesturl!)
    web.mainFrame.loadRequest(request)
```

Which presumably is why im getting the error `found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`
What am I missing here to correctly convert the `pathForResource` to a `string`?

Comment: You mean converting the resource path string to a NSURL right?

Comment: Yes, I thought I needed to get a string value? (first time trying mac app development so I may be wrong on this)

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the actual output of your println() statements.

Comment: PATH: `Optional(file:///Users/*******/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Electrical_Calculators-askhpxrxvlxbdxcfdbyosdczzquo/Build/Products/Debug/Electrical%20Calculators.app/Contents/Resources/myResource.html)`

Comment: Why are you getting a path if you need an url?

Comment: To convert to a string

Comment: you can use yourUrl.path

Comment: take a look at this answer and I think it will help you to understand how to use URLs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27650322/array-of-multiple-urls-nsfilemanager-swift/27650412#27650412

Comment: You do realise this is for mac osx not iOS right?

Comment: It makes no difference I will update the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code given in Leonardo's answer should work and is the easier and safer
method with optional binding. Here is an explanation why your
code fails:

```
let requesturl = NSURL(string: urlpath!)
```

returns `nil` because `urlpath` is a *file path* and not an *URL string*
(such as "file:///path/to/file").

If you replace that line with

```
let requesturl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlpath!)
```

then you will get the expected output.

Comment: Ok, but that gives me the same as the `urlPath` `Optional(file:///Users/*******/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Electrical_Calcula‌​tors-askhpxrxvlxbdxcfdbyosdczzquo/Build/Products/Debug/Electrical%20Calculators.a‌​pp/Contents/Resources/myResource.html)`

Comment: I think the problem is now displaying the html file as im getting it loaded now (sort of), thanks for explanation

Comment: @JSA986: Strange, I have tested your exact code, and the first println produced the output `resource path = Optional("/Users/.../Build/Products/Debug/Electrical Calculator.app/Contents/Resources/myResource.html")`, without `file:///`.

Answer (score 4):

```
if let myFileUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("yourFile", withExtension: "html"){
            // do whatever with your url
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5

```swift
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myResource", ofType: "html")
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
```