# Equivalent Casting of JPEG to Data, but with .mov files in Swift

Tags: swift, aws-amplify, coercion, avasset

I have some code that works fine, using Amplify to push and pull images from an AWS-S3 bucket.

```
let uploadTask = Amplify.Storage.uploadData(key: imageKey, data: srcData, options: nil)
        Task {
            for await progress in await uploadTask.progress {
                print("Progress: \(progress)")
            }
        }
        do {
            let value = try await uploadTask.value
            print("Completed: \(value)")
            return true
        } catch {
            print("problem uploading \(error)")
        }
        return false
```

This is fine for the upload, and there's corresponding code working for the download.

But my goal is to move .mov files up to AWS from inside an app, and to retrieve them, also from the app. I think what I've got will work, but the missing piece is how to

- convert the .mov file (or other Mac compatible movie format) to data for upload
- convert the retrieved data back to a .mov file for cacheing or playing (not streaming).

The movies are small (<15Mb) so holding them in memory won't be a problem, since a maximum of 10 would be available to play at one time, in case that matters. But they will be saved to the Caches Directory.

I assume this is either an AVAsset or an AVURLAsset, but I haven't understood what the process that would be the equivalent of `<UIImage>.jpegData(etc.…)` but for timebases media is.

Comment: If you have working code for up and downloading files then why do you need to change anything, why do you need to convert from/to Data?

Comment: Because the Amplify API expects Data, not files. The question is about how you transform .mov files into data, and back. When moving jpegs up and down, I still have to transform them, but the Swift syntax for that is easy to find. I don't know what it is for media like .mov files.

Comment: Also, but not mentioned: there is a probably use case where they will be stored as Binary Blobs in some DB somewhere outside of AWS, so that may also require, as would encryption possibly.

Comment: last comment: I can see that I was confusing in my explanation, by saying I "wanted to move files"; but the context is an argument from the Amplify method that is explicitly named "data", not "url" or something else.

Comment: This might be helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449845/swift-ios-10-how-to-download-a-video-and-store-within-the-app

Comment: If you have a URL to a file then why don't you simply create a `Data` instance using the `Data(contentsOf:)` initializer?

Comment: @HangarRash that I can do, the question was more focused on the conversion back. The conversion to data was asked primarily because I wasn't sure if there were some symmetrical pair of methods. At this point, I'm using an Amplify method that accepts a local url and downloads data as a file. Not quite what I wanted, since in some situations I don't want to accumulate files in the user's directories, but workable for now.

Comment: On the conversion back, you will get data from the server. Save the data to a file and you're done. No conversion needed. Otherwise, what else do you want to do with the data? It's really unclear what issue you are having. You have a file of data and you want to send the data to a server. No conversion needed. You get data from a server and you want to save the data to a file. No conversion needed. The fact that they are .mov files is totally irrelevant, it's just data.