# Downloaded PDF file but cannot locate it

Tags: ios, swift

I used swift code to download a PDF file. It says that it is saved to destiantion 
`file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/25E45F2F-41EA-4EAB-8D8A-97F43A209D36/Documents/model-1.pdf`

However when I open files from my iPhone I cannot find the file named "model-1.pdf" anywhere.

The code I used was from : [Download file from server using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27540068/download-file-from-server-using-swift)

```
        let documentsUrl = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        // your destination file url
        let destination = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(pathURL.lastPathComponent)
        print(destination)
        // check if it exists before downloading it
        if FileManager().fileExists(atPath: destination.path) {
            print("The file already exists at path")
        } else {
            //  if the file doesn't exist
            //  just download the data from your url
            URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: pathURL, completionHandler: { (location, response, error) in
                // after downloading your data you need to save it to your destination url
                guard
                    let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                    let location = location, error == nil
                    else {
                        self.showAlert(title: NSLocalizedString("Error", comment: "") , message: "")
                        return }
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destination)
                    print("file saved")
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }).resume()
        }
```

Comment: Wouldn’t see it in “files” on your iPhone. It would get sandboxed in the protected app space. If you run the app in a simulator you would be able to view the file on your Mac.

Comment: @SGraham If I want it to show in "files" what should I do then ?

Comment: There is a way to expose your app’s files. Check this out: https://www.appcoda.com/files-app-integration/

Comment: @SGraham Yeah that worked.. Thank you